# Does installing a package require internet in Ubuntu?

Tags: python-2.7

Does this command require internet:

sudo apt-get install python-tk

I am using Ubuntu 13.04.
 Every time I try, it says that it does not contain installable candidate

Comment: Yes, It's require

Comment: Thanks a lot there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, unless you have a local repository (PPA) which you defined to be searchable.. It needs to download it from somewhere. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu